# Javascript - Find (not remove) elements with duplicate properties in an object array

Tags: javascript, mapreduce

I want to fetch an object array, check if multiple properties are duplicate at the same time. Finally, the duplicate elements are meant to be alerted. i.e. for the array:

```
[
  {
    "language" : "english",
    "type" : "a",
    "value" : "value1"
  },
  {
    "language" : "english",
    "type" : "a",
    "value" : "value2"
  },
  {
    "language" : "english",
    "type" : "b",
    "value" : "value3"
  },    
  {
    "language" : "spanish",
    "type" : "a",
    "value" : "valor1"
  }
];
```

The alert should be: **"Too many elements with language *english* and type *a*"**.

I sought for it, yet the answers were either dirty map/reduce implementations that made VisualStudio2015 pissed off or finding a full duplicates (not only based on specific properties)

Comment: What if there are several duplicates on several language/type pairs? Do you want to alert on the first duplicate found or all of them?

Comment: I want all of them prompted.

Comment: The solution you accepted is just hard-coded... It doesn't find duplicate properties, but just hard-codes that they are duplicate, see the `console.log`.

Comment: @user4636715 Please let me know if I misread the question. It is not obvious to me that the duplicate properties need to be found dynamically. By reading it again, I see that it can be understood that way, though.

Comment: @Arnauld It is enough for me to alert the message indeed. I am going to ask the data provider to re-send the list to me where there are no duplicates. Hence, your way works for me anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance wise, I think the best option is to iterate on each element of the list while updating a counter of the encountered keys.

You want to alert when `counter == 2`. You should not test `counter > 1` because it would repeat the same alert several times, when you have more than 2 pairs with the same language and same type.

```js
var list = [{
    "language" : "english",
    "type" : "a",
    "value" : "value1"
  },{
    "language" : "english",
    "type" : "a",
    "value" : "value2"
  },{
    "language" : "english",
    "type" : "a",
    "value" : "value3"
  },{
    "language" : "english",
    "type" : "b",
    "value" : "value3"
  },{
    "language" : "spanish",
    "type" : "a",
    "value" : "valor1"
  },{
    "language" : "spanish",
    "type" : "a",
    "value" : "valor2"
}];

var counter = {};

list.forEach(function(o) {
  var key = o.language + '|' + o.type;
  if((counter[key] = (counter[key] || 0) + 1) == 2) {
    console.log('Too many elements with language '+o.language+' and type '+o.type);
  }
});
```